# Function not returning a particular value

Tags: python, function, jupyter, return-value, equation

I am modelling an equation with these parameters but when i try to call the function for xi = 0, the function does not return any value.

```
def zp(T, xi, sig, mu):
    p = 1/T
    yp = -log(1 - p)
    if xi == 0:
        zp = mu - sig*log(yp);
    else:
        zp = mu - (sig/xi)*(1-(yp**-xi));
        return(zp)

zp(5, 0, 6, 2)
```

Comment: You didn't return in both branches of the if statement.

Comment: The `return(zp)` statement appears to be part of `else` block. Add a new line before `return` and de-indent it to suggest that it is outside of the `if` and `else` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the return is indented incorrectly?

```
def zp(T, xi, sig, mu):
    p = 1 / T
    yp = -log(1 - p)

    if xi == 0:
        zp = mu - sig * log(yp)
    else:
        zp = mu - (sig / xi) * (1 - (yp ** -xi))

    return zp
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it. Indentation was incorrect.

Comment: One more thing, why does the function return a different value than what I calculated manually with a calculator. is there anything wrong with the log here

Comment: @Dawar as per the logic of the method, I'm unsure. Maybe add some print statements to help debug. e.g. `print(f"T={T}, p=1/T={p}, yp=-log(1-p)={yp}")`

Comment: I tried this. It returned an error message T is not defined

Comment: Add it inside the function before the return. `T` is scoped to the function, unless you changed the variable name.

Comment: It was a problem with the log. The calculator calculates it to the base 10 while python to the base e. I imported math and modified the argument to                                                                               math.log10()